# Cannot install Netbeans 7 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, netbeans

I'm having problems installing Netbeans 7.0 on my machine. The installer works but then the system suddenly restarts. How do I troubleshoot this one?
Here's what I got:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   c2
  BCP1: 00000007
  BCP2: 00001097
  BCP3: 0A050820
  BCP4: BDD3A108
  OS Version:   6_1_7600
  Service Pack: 0_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\042511-26488-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Aizen\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-49202-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is make sure the installer you have isn't corrupted.  Download the install file again.  If possible, install the same file on another system.

BCCode (bug check code) c2 (or 0x000000C2) is BAD_POOL_CALL.  That is most typically caused by (surprise, surprise) bad drivers.

You can analyze the dump file and determine the likely cause of the problem or the filename of the program causing the exception, which will then lead you to the driver causing the problem.

You can try [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to do it, but I have never used it myself so I cannot speak to how well it works.

I usually follow Microsoft's instructions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263) but that's much more complex to do.  You want to start about halfway through where it says "You can also read small memory dump files by using the WinDbg tool or the KD.exe tool."  (Not sure if WinDbg is available in the current version of the debug tools as sometimes it never shows up for me for some reason, so you might need to use KD.exe; all you need to install from the web SDK downloader is the Debuger.)  It's important that you run this on the computer where the error occurred so it can find the files it needs.  Run KD.exe, and use the sample commands in the KB article to analyze the dump file.  When you run `!analyze -v` the output should give you an idea of where things went pear-shaped.

If you get a MS file like ntoskrnl.exe, then I would begin to suspect corrupt disk (run chkdsk) or bad hardware (disk or memory, then system board).

Comment: tried it on my xp, still on the same machine. And it installed without problems. I'm now using it on my windows 7 using the one that I installed on xp